# Running into a segfault when referencing pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm taking an intro to C programming course, and I'm trying to understand pointers, and how exactly they work. I tried to pass just the variable `counter` through `gameRuntime();`, but `counter` wasn't being returned towards after the while loop. So, I opted to use a pointer. And now I'm in a bigger mess than I started.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int *gameRuntime(int *counter)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 100 + 1;
    printf("> %d <\n", random);
        int guess;
        *counter = 1;
        int local_counter = (*counter);
        while ((guess != random) && (local_counter <= 10))
        {
            printf("\n-----------------------\n");
            printf("What is your guess?\n-----------------------\n> ");
            scanf("%d", &guess);

            if ((guess > 100) || (guess < 1))
            {
                printf("Please choose a number between 1 and 100\n");
            }
            else if (guess < random)
            {
                printf("My number is larger than %d!\n", guess);
                    local_counter++;
                printf("%d guesses left!\n", (11 - local_counter));
            }
            else if (guess > random)
            {
                printf("My number is less than %d!\n", guess);
                    local_counter++;
                printf("%d guesses left!\n", (11 - local_counter));
            }
            else if (guess == random)
            {
                printf("You guessed it! My number was %d!\n", random);
                printf("You found it with just %d guess(es)!\n", local_counter);
            }
        }
        (*counter) = local_counter;
        return counter;
}

int main()
{
    char quit;
    int counter;
    int random;

    printf("Welcome to the Number Guess Game!\n");
    printf("I chose a number between 1 and 100 and you have only 10 chances to guess it!\n\n");
    printf("Continue? [Y\\N]\n\n> ");
    scanf("%c", &quit);
    if ((quit == 'n') || (quit == 'N'))
    {
        printf("Exiting....");
            return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n=*=+=*=+=*=+=*==*=+=*=+=*=+=*==*=+=*=+=*=+=*==*=+=*=+=+*\n");
        printf("   ~       ~       ~       Ready?       ~       ~       ~   \n");
        printf("=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*=+=*\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n-----------------------");
        printf("\nOk, I've made up my mind!\n");
        printf("-----------------------\n");
    }

    gameRuntime(counter);
    printf("\n---%d---\n", counter);

    char continueGame;
    while ((continueGame != 'N') || (continueGame != 'n'))
    {
        printf("\n---%d---\n", counter);
        if (counter >= 10)
        {
            printf("SORRY! You could not find my number with 10 guesses!\n");
            printf("My number was %d\n", random);
            printf("Maybe next time!\n");
            printf("\nTry again? [Y\\N]\n");
            scanf(" %c", &continueGame);

            if ((continueGame == 'Y') || (continueGame == 'y'))
            {
                gameRuntime(counter);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Thanks for playing! See you later!");
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Play again? [Y\\N]\n> ");
            scanf(" %c", &continueGame);

            if ((continueGame == 'Y') || (continueGame == 'y'))
            {
                gameRuntime(counter);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nThanks for playing! See you later!");
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, TIA

Comment: `gameRuntime(counter);` -> `gameRuntime(&counter);` Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: If your compiler didn't tell you exactly what the problem is, get a new compiler! Mine spits out several warnings that point directly to the problem.

Comment: A good way to avoid errors like that is to enable all compiler warnings, and fix them before running your code.

Comment: Besides compiler errors there are also logic errors in your code. Leaving everything aside, the reason your code did not work as expected without pointers ("I tried to pass just the variable counter through gameRuntime()...") is that you ran the function gameRuntime(counter) but did not save/assign the return value (processed new value of counter) of this function and didn't use this new value in your code. Just revert your code to the state before using pointers and instead of gameRuntime(counter) use counter=gameRuntime(counter);

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
gameRuntime(counter);
```

to

```
gameRuntime(&counter);
```

You are passing the value of `counter`, and then you used it like if it was the address of something (*you dereferenced the pointer*). It does compile because pointers and `int`s are interchangeable in c, but that doesn't mean that the behavior is defined. It should however, generate a warning about pointer to `int` conversion. You can also, convert all warnings to errors to prevent compilation in case of a warning.

Warnings can be ignored in very rare cases, so as a rule of thumb make your compiler warn about everything it can and if possible, let it treat warnings as errors.

By applying the suggested fix, you pass the address of `counter`, which is a pointer holding the location of `counter` in memory, thus you can then affect the value at that location by dereferencing the pointer.